# How can you properly make a Stack with Integers on BlueJ?

Tags: java, bluej

I've been using BlueJ for a while now and recently, we've started making and working on Stacks and Arrays in my class. This is basically what I have to do currently:

Create the class "StackTest", which contains a Stack called "zahlen" with values of the type "Integer".  Add the numbers 5, 10, 50 and 30 to the Stack respectively. Finally, run the Stack and it should show all values that are bigger than 10 in the console.

They also gave us certain keywords that have to be used at least once in the class: [Keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmpBc.png)

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class StackTest
{
public StackTest(){
    Stack zahlen = new Stack();
    zahlen.push(5);
    zahlen.push(10);
    zahlen.push(50);
    zahlen.push(30);
    while (!zahlen.isEmpty()){
        if(zahlen.top()>10){
        }
    zahlen.pop();
  }
 }
}
```

My problem is that first of all, I don't know what exactly the Integer in parenthesis is or what it can be used for (talking about `(Integer)` ) and I also don't know how you can check if the top number ( `zahlen.top()` ) can be used in the if command.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be genuinely worth your while to read up on the Stack class in the official Java documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

It can be a bit dense, but it contains a lot of useful information.  This will give you the info you need regardless of using BlueJ, Eclipse, or any other IDE.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

A stack follows LIFO rule (Last-In-First-Out). Think of a stack like a stack of dirty plates that you want to clean, to clean a plate you would take a plate on top of the stack rather than reach for the bottom or the middle. In your case rather than a stack of dirty plates, it's a stack of Integers.

Once you've created your stack collection, you `push()` elements into the stack in your code example it would look something like this:

```
|30|
|50|
|10|
|5 |
 ¯¯
```

Note that you don't have access to any of elements aside from the top of stack (30 in this case). To gain access to elements below you have to `pop()` the stack which will remove it from the collection.

For example:

```
int value = zahlen.pop();
```

will cause value to be equal to 30 and your new stack collection will look like this:

```
|  |
|50|
|10|
|5 |
 ¯¯
```

You can now use value to check whether or not it's greater than 10 then use
`System.out.println()` to print out the value to the console, simply loop this till your stack is empty. If you wish to look at the value on top of the stack without popping it off you can use peek() method.